# Android parsing difficulties

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have some difficulties parsing a json file that is located on the internet from android.
Here is the content of the Json file:

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.0803,
    "city": {
        "id": 2643743,
        "name": "London",
        "coord": {
            "lon": -0.12574,
            "lat": 51.50853
        },
        "country": "GB",
        "population": 1000000
    },
    "cnt": 2,
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1389182400,
            "temp": {
                "day": 9.72,
                "min": 9.72,
                "max": 11.25,
                "night": 11.25,
                "eve": 9.72,
                "morn": 9.72
            },
            "pressure": 1016.8,
            "humidity": 95,
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 500,
                    "main": "Rain",
                    "description": "light rain",
                    "icon": "10d"
                }
            ],
            "speed": 6,
            "deg": 162,
            "clouds": 80,
            "rain": 2
        },
        {
            "dt": 1389268800,
            "temp": {
                "day": 9.75,
                "min": 4.56,
                "max": 11.22,
                "night": 4.56,
                "eve": 6.76,
                "morn": 11.22
            },
            "pressure": 1006.76,
            "humidity": 95,
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 500,
                    "main": "Rain",
                    "description": "light rain",
                    "icon": "10d"
                }
            ],
            "speed": 9.16,
            "deg": 267,
            "clouds": 44,
            "rain": 0.5
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like some help because I don't know how to parse the list. I keep getting the app crashing.

Comment: Post the code you use which produces this "crash".

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to give us more help: Do you have crash logs? What have you tried?

[jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) confirms that your JSON is valid. If I understand your intention, you can deserialise this to a `JSONObject` as follows:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myString);
```

Once you have this, you can access values as follows:

```
double speed = obj.getJSONArray("list")
                            .getJSONObject(2)
                            .getDouble("speed");
```

Comment: I am just trying to get all the keys inside de list arrays. Here are a part of my code that I cleaned for not crashing:

Comment: JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
         String strParsedValue = null;
         try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("list");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
         JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
         // here you can get id,name,city...
          int dt = objJson.getInt("dt");
          String pressure =objJson.getString("pressure"); 
          String humidity=objJson.getString("humidity"); 
          Log.d("gender",""+pressure);
          
    }
    
   }

Comment: @YanP Is the value for "pressure" really a String? Ditto "humidity"?

Comment: catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: @SK9.Yes, it is. Is it that bad ?

Comment: @YanP Only that they look more like doubles than Strings to me. So yes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a JSON object out of the string and then just call the get methods for the pieces you're looking for.  For instance:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
Date myDOB = new Date(jsonObject.getLong(DOB_KEY));
```

for the pieces that are embedded further, you can call getJSONObject(key) and then parse that section seperately.  For instance:

```
JSONObject location = jsonObject.getJSONObject(LOCATION_KEY);
myLocation = new Location("");
myLocation.setLatitude(location.getDouble(LOCATION_LATITUDE_KEY));
myLocation.setLongitude(location.getDouble(LOCATION_LONGITUDE_KEY));
```